# NULL value returns in Mock framework in UnitTesting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I am going to create a user registration method test using an unit test project. Please refer the code below

```
 [TestClass]
 public class PersonRegistration
  {
    private ILoggingService _loggingService;
    private IUserManager _userManager;
    public PersonRegistration(IUserManager userManager, ILoggingService 
    loggingService)
    {
        this._userManager = userManager;
        this._loggingService = loggingService;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        RegisterBindingModel model = new RegisterBindingModel();
        AccountController ac = new AccountController(_userManager, _loggingService);
        model.UserName = "test123@gmail.com";
        var result = ac.Register(model);
        Assert.AreEqual("User Registered Successfully", result);
    }
```

In the above code, when I ran the test case file it says

> Unable to get default constructor for class ****.Test.Controllers.PersonRegistraion

To overcome that issue I have added a default constructor without any parameters. The first issue solved. But then `_userManager` and `_loggingService` become NULL. See Image 1.

[image: Image 1]

It throws a Null Reference exception (Image 2)

[image: Image 2]

So I used Moq (`Using Moq`) to fill up the interfaces like below.

```
[TestClass]
public class PersonRegistration
  {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var mockService = new Mock<ILoggingService>();
         var mockManager = new Mock<IUserManager>();
        RegisterBindingModel model = new RegisterBindingModel();
        AccountController ac = new AccountController(mockManager.Object, mockService.Object);
        model.UserName = "test123@gmail.com";
        var result = ac.Register(model);
        Assert.AreEqual("User Registered Successfully", result);
    }
}
```

[image: Image 3]

Now the code traverses up to `Register()`, But It returns the result as `NULL`. Is that due to invalid Mock object? I can run the whole process properly inside the WebApi project. But the same scenario returns null in the Unit Test project.

Interface `IUserManager`

```
public interface IUserManager : IDisposable
{
 Task<string> Register(RegisterBindingModel model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should be writing the test cases in a separate unit test class. The first error was thrown because VS was unable to run the unit test method, that belonged to the PersonRegistration class, which did not have a public constructor.

You are on the right track mocking the interfaces. The issue is not due to invalid mock objects. What you should do is, mock the function as follows:

```
mockManager.Setup(it => it.Register(It.IsAny<RegisterBindingModel>()))
           .Returns(Task.FromResult(string.Empty));
```

Comment: Thank you @ashin. I am inside a separate Test Class. And where can I place the above code you have given.

Comment: right after the following statement in your test method:  var mockManager = new Mock<IUserManager>();

Comment: There is an issue with
`Returns(new Result());` `Result()` could not be found

Comment: it's the type that corresponds to the return value of IUserManager.Register method

Comment: I still didn't get it. What should be the value there ? It indicates an error

Comment: could you please share the IUserManager interface? you need to replace 'Result' with the return type of the Register method :)

Comment: Modified the code. Please have a look in the bottom of the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145706/discussion-between-ashin-and-harsha-w).